# Macbook white screen with background visible

Tags: display

I'm not sure what got into my system. It was working just fine but then this happened.

[image]

Strange this is, even after I turn my computer off, when I turn on I can see the background of my mac and some applications opened (feels as if the computer wasn't turned off).

Please help!

Comment: That’s a hardware issue.  It looks like the backlight controller is failing.  You need to take it in for service

Comment: Does [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) work?

Comment: You've got the display calibration panel open, which will disable proper colour management until it it closed. Quit it & see what happens. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggvlx.jpg

Comment: @Allan
Damn, any way I can fix it myself? I don't have time to give this device for so many days..

Comment: @lhf
I'm scared that I would loose my data..

Comment: @Tetsujin
I was just testing out something..I closed it but it is still the same.

Comment: Can you attach an external monitor?

Comment: @lhf
Just did, the external monitor seems to be working perfectly fine with crisp colours.

Comment: OK, it was a long-shot but worth testing. Check it in recovery mode, just in case, but I'd guess Allan's right; you have a hardware screen issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin
Yes, I would boot in recovery mode eventually..just wondering what caused this issue ...

Comment: You've already done the other tests to ensure it's not the logic board/GPU.  I've seen it before - the backlight can't regulate it self and goes "full blast."  Usually had to replace the back light controller, sometimes the display assembly.

Comment: @Allan Thanks Allan, I'll look up a repair shop and head over there then.